# MySQL not showing updated data even after commit

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I am using two windows as I want to implement concept of transaction.

Window1: `begin;`

Window1: `update employee set salary = 45000 where ssn = '123456789';`

Window2: `begin;`

Window2: `select * from employee where ssn = '123456789';`

Here, this command shows me previous data which is correct.

Window1: `commit;`

Window2: `select * from employee where ssn = '123456789';`

Here, I should get the updated salary of 45000. But my window 2 is showing previous data only. Where am I doing the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You expectations are incorrect, that's all. What transactions see from each other's work is determined by the so called [transaction isolation levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level). By default, mysql uses [repeatable read isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-consistent-read.html), which means:

> If the transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ (the default
>   level), all consistent reads within the same transaction read the
>   snapshot established by the first such read in that transaction. You
>   can get a fresher snapshot for your queries by committing the current
>   transaction and after that issuing new queries.

You can change the isolation level to read committed to enable the behaviour you expect:

> With READ COMMITTED isolation level, each consistent read within a transaction sets and reads its own fresh snapshot.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But i just want to know how to change the DEFAULT TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in My SQL to Read Committed GLOBALLY.